# TestFlight Provide feedback button

Tags: ios, testflight, feedback, beta-testing

I am using latest testflight version for iOS 8. I added myself as internal tester and now when I open the application using testflight, nowhere I can find the feedback button.

Please let me know if anybody has any clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You provide feedback in the Testflight app.

1. Open the Testflight app.
2. Tap on the icon of the application you want to provide feedback on.
3. Tap "Send Feedback" in the center towards the top of the screen.

If you are not seeing the feedback button then make sure that you have set a feedback email address for the build in iTunesConnect.

Comment: Thanks you, but I am aware that there is "Send Feedback" button on app details page and that is what I am trying to figure out, why it is not there.

Comment: Have you added a feedback email address for the build in iTunesConnect?

Comment: Ohh, I think this was what I missed and that is what probably causing this. I will add one and check if it resolves the problem.

Comment: I have a feedback email address setup in iTunesConnect but still don't see a 'send feedback' button.  Any other settings you need to check?

Comment: As well, the "Submit Feedback" button won't show up for Internal Testing builds on TestFlight. Only external testing.

Answer (score 2):

People still asked it today so please after checking Your TestFight configuration, remember one more thing: Tester has to have Apple Mail app configured in order for TF feedback to work. For Apple this seems natural and they think that every iPhone user has built-in iOS Mail app configured. But in reality, many people simply don't use it and prefer other e-mail apps. For these people feedback button will appear hidden in TestFlight. I tested it myself and it works.