# Missing "Provide Feedback" button in TestFlight for iOS

Tags: ios, testflight, feedback

I've deployed a beta version via TestFlight to external testers, and I provided a feedback email in the build's information in iTunes Connect as I read in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379787/testflight-provide-feedback-button) from someone that also missed such button. However, in TestFlight app in the device, for the app to test (it is alreay installed), I only see the "Open" button at top, an rows with "Developer Website", "Notifications" and "Stop testing" at bottom...

Comment: Hi, I am also facing same issue. Were you able to resolve it and how.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) have feedback e-mail added in Testflight, to send feedback to
2) testers must have Apple Mail app configured with an e-mail to send feedback to.

I think this second requirement is why many beta testers don't get "Feedback" button in TestFlight app - it simply hides the button if it cannt find e-mail to send feedback to, and it needs Apple Mail app configured and working to do that.